# C++ get method - returning by value or by reference

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, return-value-optimization

I've go a very simple question, but unfortunately I can't figure the answer myself.

Suppose I've got some data structure that holds settings and acts like a settings map.
I have a `GetValue(const std::string& name)` method, that returns the corresponding value.

Now I'm trying to figure out - what kind of return-value approach would be better. The obvious one means making my method act like

```
std::string GetValue(const std::string& name) const
```

and return a copy of the object and rely on RVO in performance meanings.

The other one would mean making two methods

```
std::string& GetValue(...)
const std::string& GetValue(...) const
```

which generally means duplicating code or using some evil constant casts to use one of these routines twice.

### `#`Q

***What would be your choice in this kind of situation and why?***

Comment: They are not even semantically identical - you should only leave `const std::string& GetValue(...) const` unless you want things to get really ugly...

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. Do you store a copy of the thing you are returning from the function `GetValue` in the class as a member? If no, then there is only one option: Return by value `std::string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I would probably use:

```
std::string GetValue(const std::string& name) const;
// or
const std::string* GetValue(const std::string& name) const;

void SetValue(std::string name, std::string value);
```

Setter first:

- Passing by value in `SetValue` allows the compiler some optimizations that cannot be made with pass by const-reference, it's been explained in a article by Dave Abrahams, ["Want Speed? Pass by Value."](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)
- Using a `Setter` is usually better, because you can check the value being set whereas with a plain reference you have no guarantee that the caller won't do anything stupid with the data.

For the getter:

- Returning by copy seems a waste since most times you won't modify the object returned (for a settings map), however pointer or reference do mean that the object aliased will live long enough, if you can't guarantee it then the point is moot: return by value. Also copy allow to avoid exposing an internal detail, for example if you were suddenly to switch to `std::wstring` because you need some settings in UTF-8...
- If you need performance, then you are ready to do some concessions in this department. However a reference does not allow you to signal the absence of the property (unless you have some magic value) while the pointer makes it easy (NULL is already cut out for you).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, those optimizations require compiler support for rvalue references and a std lib implementation taking advantage of this. Then this should be mentioned.

Comment: He is refering to copy elision, which doesn't require move semantics.

Answer (score 6):

That depends on the usage. Should `GetValue("foo") = "bar"` make sense? In that case, return by value does not do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you can return by const reference, do. The only reason to return a memory-managing class like std::string by value is because it's a temporary string.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very "sensitive" point of C++. IMHO it's one of the weakest points of C++ design.
AFAIK there's no really good choice, which will be both look and perform good.

One point that should be mentioned that RVO optimization usually does only a part of the job. Without it a typical expression like this:

```
std::string txt = GetValue("...");
```

will actually produce 2 copies!
Depends on the compiler, but usually RVO optimization eliminates just one copy, however the other is still there.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "... however the other [copy] is still there"? If that was the case, then the optimizer would've created buggy code! AFAIK, in such cases as you show, some compilers let the function construct the return value directly in the assigned variable (`txt` in your example) and there will never be two copies (the one in the dictionary not included in that count).

Comment: In C++0x, with rvalue references, there are explicit semantics to avoid extra temporary copies in the return value of this function. There will be only 2 copies the one that's already in settings object, and the other that will wind up in the txt variable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this answer to avoid future readers who are less experienced with C++ from writing code that produces undefined behaviour.

The question doesn't specify whether the class that the Getter function belong to stores a copy of the value to be returned.

Let us deal with the return by value case first. This is the option you would normally choose.

```
std::string GetValue(const std::string& name) const
```

This is valid C++ and does not produce undefined behaviour.

The OP didn't specify how the return value is produced. It might be something like this:

```
std::string GetValue(const std::string& name) const
{
    std::string temporary = function_of_name(name);
    // for example:
    // std::string temporary = "Hello " + name + "!";
    return temporary;
}
```

In the above example, a temporary object is created inside the scope of `GetValue`. At the end of function scope it is returned, by value, which means that either a copy of the object is made, or more likely the compiler performs return value optimization (RVO) (pre and post C++ 11) and the copy is "optimized out" or "elided".

Please do not confuse this with modern C++ 11 and later "move semantics". This is a different but related concept. RVO existed *before* move semantics, and most good C++ 03 compilers will perform RVO.

The point being that returning any kind of reference here for example `std::string&` produces undefined behaviour, because the object goes out of scope at the end of the function body and the returned reference is now pointing to something that has been deleted/removed from memory. (A reference is just a pointer with extra syntactic sugar applied.)

**Second Case**

If the class stores a copy of the object to be returned then returning a reference is a valid thing to do. However it is not likely to be much faster than the first RVO case.

I can expand on this to add more detail later if necessary, but hopefully it is now clear why this is the case.