# What reasons are there for a returning by value in C++

Tags: c++

Since returning by value is most of the times less efficient than returning a reference, what are some examples where returning by value makes sense or is the only possible way to do it?

edit: I phrased my question incorrectly. I know that with built-in types it is often more efficient to return by value I was mostly referring to cases where you are returning a user-defined type that is larger than a pointer.

Comment: What makes you think it's less efficient?  Have you looked at what the compiler generates?

Comment: *returning by value is most of the times less efficient than returning a reference* is not true, there is always return value optimization.

Comment: How many times have you returned a pointer by reference?

Comment: If the function creates a new (stack-allocated) value of that type then you cannot return by reference, since this reference is invalid. For instance, look at string::substr which returns a new string object by value.

Comment: Good luck for returning by reference a variable that is local to a function...

Comment: I understand that the compiler may optimize it to make it more efficient but when you are writing the program you cannot can not know in advance if that optimzation will be possible and the default behavior is to create a copy which will be less efficient in all cases that the objects size is larger than a pointer.

Comment: Since returning by reference is most of the times less correct than returning by value, what are some examples where returning by reference makes sense or is the only possible way to do it?

Comment: @user199421, The default behaviour is (N)RVO, if applicable, which any reasonable compiler will do when it can, then moving it, which can be much more efficient than copying, and then copying.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: E.g. `map::operator[]`.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the big point here - returning by reference doesn't always makes sense, nor is it always legal. Returning a local by reference leads to undefined behavior. You can return by reference a variable that lives beyond the scope of the function, which can be:

- dynamically allocated - bad idea, you have to manage the lifetime yourself
- member of a class - this is commonly used with getters that have 2 versions: one that returns a reference & you can modify the member or a `const` getter that returns a `const` reference
- a `static` local variable (or any variable with static storage) - more often than not, this isn't needed in functions just for returning by reference.

NRVO makes return by value feasible in practice, so unless you have clear measurements that indicate return by value is a bottleneck don't worry about it. Worry instead about the semantics of what either imply.

Answer (score 3):

Returning by value is **no less efficient** in two cases: **1** if you're moving an object (C++11) and **2** if the compiler can elide the copy or optimise the return value away (always possible for built-in types, see also JaredPar's answer).

There are **several advantages**: **1** no variable needs to be declared prior to the function call (which may not always be possible) and the returned variable type is detectable via `auto` **2** the intent of setting the returned variable is obvious.

```
void foo(some_type &obj_ref);
some_type bar();

// using reference
some_type A;          // requires default constructor for A
foo(A);               // modification of A is not obvious

// returning a value
auto B = bar();       // move or copy construction of B
```

Note that the last statement can either use return-value optimisation or move semantics (C++11)

Comment: Case #1 in the first paragraph is too general (and thus incorrect).

Comment: Ignoring C++ move semantics, is counting on RVO something that is considered a good practice? Isn't this moving away from the standard and relying on compiler specific behavior? How would you know in advance that a compiler will optimize for you something that, on the surface, can be improved by changing the design and returning a reference?

Comment: For some value of "improved". Fighting the compiler rarely ends in good.

Comment: You should realise that you are relying on compiler specific behaviour as well: you are assuming a compiler that produces better code if you return by reference (which most of the time is just wrong, not fast or slow, but wrong, though I'm pretending it is not just to indulge you in your discussion). The fact is, if you care about performance, but don't consider the compiler, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is what g++ produces by default when using the -O3 flag for a method that returns an integer by reference:

```
void Foo(int& rc) {
    rc = 42;
}
```

Becomes:

```
__Z3FooRi:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:   
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    $42, (%rdi)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

Here's the same method returning by value:

```
int Foo() {
  return 42;
}
```

Becomes:

```
__Z3Foov:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    $42, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

As you can see, your premise is flawed.  Both versions result in nearly identical machine code.

People have been producing optimizing compilers for C/C++ for three decades.  You can assume they've thought of any common use cases, and done their damnedest to ensure that any common code pattern will produce optimal code.  Never, ever change your coding style to improve performance unless you are armed with profiling results that definitively prove that it there is a difference.  Far too many of these sorts of "optimizations" not only make code harder to read, but actually make performance worse.

**EDIT**

Here's a similar comparison with a larger type.  Here, both methods return the following `struct`:

```
struct Bar
{
    unsigned int a;
    unsigned int b;
    unsigned int c;
    unsigned int d;
};
```

This code:

```
void Foo(Bar& rc) {
    rc.a = 1;
    rc.b = 2;
    rc.c = 3;
    rc.d = 4;
}
```

produces this output:

```
__Z3FooR3Bar:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    $1, (%rdi)
    movl    $2, 4(%rdi)
    movl    $3, 8(%rdi)
    movl    $4, 12(%rdi)
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Leh_func_end1:

On the other hand, this return by value version:

```
Bar Foo() {
    Bar rc;
    rc.a = 1;
    rc.a = 2;
    rc.a = 3;
    rc.a = 4;

    return rc;
}
```

ends up producing *fewer* machine code instructions:

```
__Z3Foov:
Leh_func_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp1:
    movl    $4, %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Leh_func_end1:
```

If you want to do these comparisons yourself in g++, use `g++ -S -O3`.  Other compilers will have similar methods of producing assembly.

Comment: please see my comment on Walter's answer to understand where I'm coming from. What would be a good rule of thumb to decide if the a function should return by value or by reference?

Comment: The first rule of thumb: never make a coding decision based on performance without either looking at timings from a profiler, or examining the actual compiler output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are starting this question with the incorrect assumption that returning by value is less efficient than other forms of return.  This is just simply not the case for a few reasons

- Simple built-in types like `int`, `char`, etc ...  can be returned via a register
- Even large values can be returned by value efficiently due to named return value optimization ([NRVO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/02/03/66739.aspx))

There are certainly cases where return by value is inefficient.  However this does not mean that every case is so.

Answer (score 2):

A Beginner's Answer:

Returning by value makes sense if I do not need the variables I am passing to be changed but just want the value of the solution of the function for purposes like printing the value and I do not need to store the answer anywhere!

Just trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is disputable (comments have been given), but for the question: I recommend reading

Scott Meyers' *Effective C++ (Third Edition)*,
**Item 21: Don't try to return a reference when you must return an object.**

The example is (slightly modified):

```
class Rational {
public:
    Rational(int numerator = 0, int denominator = 1)
        : n(numerator), d(denominator) {}

    // ...

private:
    int n, d;

    friend Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs);
};
```

The use is like this:

```
    Rational a(1, 2);    // a = 1/2
    Rational b(3, 5);    // b = 3/5

    Rational c = a * b;  // c should be 3/10
```

And the implementation:

```
Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs)
{
    Rational result(lhs.n * rhs.n, lhs.d * rhs.d);
    // Would you return that local variable by reference?
    //  You don't want a dangling reference...
    //  Returning by value is the correct thing to do.
    return result;
}
```

or shorter:

```
Rational operator*(const Rational& lhs, const Rational& rhs)
{
    return Rational(lhs.n * rhs.n, lhs.d * rhs.d);
}
```

(you can make it `inline` and put it in the header).

Read the complete Item for a review of the "alternatives" (dynamic allocation, static variables...) and a detailed argumentation of why they're all bad (that's the point: *they're all bad*: subtly dangerous or even downright incorrect).

Finally, quoting from there:

> The right way to write a function that must return a new object is to
>   have that function return a new object.

So: when it's the natural semantics, just return by value.

Answer (score 0):

You return by value for example when you want to modify the returned object without affecting the object which member function was called. In the following example you can modify `b` (which is returned by value) without changing object `a` (and value `_val` inside it):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A(int val) : _val(val){}
    int val(){return _val;}
private:
    int _val;
};

int main()
{
        A a(3);
        int b = a.val();
        ++b;
        cout << "a.val() = " << a.val() << endl;
        cout << "b = " << b << endl;
}
```

See [more reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939165/c-get-method-returning-by-value-or-by-reference)

Comment: @milleniumbug, I mean you can modify the returned object while keeping the object inside container unchanged. Thanx, this was not clear before

Comment: Ok, now that the answer have been corrected, I removed the downvote.